# Activiti: Suspending a task to introduce alternate flow, and reviving it again

Tags: activiti

I have following process design currently:

> start-event -> user-task-A -> user-task-B -> end-event

As shown, user-task-A is followed by user-task-B on completion.

I need to modify it for a requirement as per which user working on user-task-A can suspend it because he/she has some queries over it. If this happens then user-task-B is not to be created, and instead a new user task is to be created for resolution of those queries. And when those queries are answered, user-task-A has to be revived and normal course follows.

What I understand is that user tasks in activiti can't be suspended. Entire process needs to be suspended.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can achieve this by modelling that requirement into the business process:

```
start -> user-task-A -> exclusive gateway (is task done?) 
                          -> yes -> user-task-B
                          -> no -> sub process for answering queries 
                                     -> go back to user-task-A
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I have a query here. Wont' we need to complete user-task-A to activate exclusive gateway decision?And if yes,then it means we can't go back to user-task-A as its completed.

Comment: You can complete User-Task-A with different outputs.. using a variable so the process can understand if the task was really completed or it requires further queries to be resolved. After resolving the queries, the User-Task-A can be recreated with new data, and at that point it can be really "logically" completed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options here. Salaboys answer is one of these options.
When I need to include fragments of process inline I typically use Signal events to trigger the fragment and then wait for completion (another signal event) to continue.

This approach keeps the model simple and enables you to maintain each of the fragments independently (kind of like modularisation with a consistent interface).

Comment: ' When I need to include fragments of process inline'...can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Greg approach is also good.. it really depends on the requirements. Signals are good and it helps in some cases, as soon as they are well understood and are used consistently.

Comment: Manroid, Consider a scenario :

task1 -> Task2 -> Task3
          -> Task2a -> task2b -> Task3

Task2 and Task2a/Task2b are independant processes with a consistent interface (variables in and out).

You can selectively call either of these flows as a dynamic sub-process, via an exclusive gateway, via an event gateway or using signals. All have their advantages and disadvantages depending on he scenario.
With signals, each of the sub flows (fragments) have a signal start event and sent a completed signal to release the parent flow.